# send gpio commands from rpi python script to another rpi

Tags: gpio, python

it is possible to control the Gpio of a raspberry pi connected by WiFi by another raspberry pi by a python script?
I need to Connect\disconect some electric loads of my house switchboard, controled by a script runnig in a raspberry PI in my garage, this one manage the solar system like the charge of the baterries. Try to use a remote controle AC switch but is to far and ins't reayable.

Answer (score 1):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module lets you control many networked Pis from one Python script.

The controlling script can be running on Windows, Mac, Linux, or a Raspberry Pi, i.e. anything which can run Python.

The Pis to be controlled each require the pigpio [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) to be running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) module to create a server on your pi which will make the GPIO actions. Then you can connect with your second pi as a client to that server an send your commands.

Basic exmaple from the docs:

server.py

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        self.gpio_action()

    def gpio_action(self):
        # do your gpio here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 9999

    # Create the server, binding on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "<ip-to-server>", 9999
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")

finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
```