# How do I send GPIO variables to another Pi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, wifi, bluetooth

I am very inexperienced with Python.  I have two Raspberry Pi computers and want to use them in a robot design.  I want a program that creates a WiFi network and broadcasts variables taken from the GPIO pins on that WiFi network.  I want the other one to read those broadcast variables and output them to the GPIO pins.  This would basically be a TX/RX program that uses WiFi.  Bluetooth would also be an option as both of the PIs in the design are going to be Bluetooth ready.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Related and possible dupe: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32816/19949

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send gpio commands from rpi python script to another rpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32816/send-gpio-commands-from-rpi-python-script-to-another-rpi)

Answer (score 1):

> [pidpgiod](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) is a utility which launches the pigpio library as a daemon.
>
> Once launched the pigpio library runs in the background accepting commands from the pipe and socket interfaces.

In other words it allows control of the GPIO on multiple networked Pis by running the pigpio daemon on each of them. Utilizing sockets (Layer 4: Transport Layer) that should be rather independent of the underlying network architecture, be that ethernet or Bluetooth.